# Java-Prolog wrong Results

Tags: java, prolog, jpl

I made a query with Org.JPL7 in Java, and I tried to do it several times in diferent ways but it gave to me a lot of wrong results. The code in .pl file is the next.

```
loco(eso,eso1).
loco(eso3,eso2).
```

and the Java code is the next.

```
Query q2= new Query(new Compound("loco", new Term[] {new Variable("X")}));

    q2.open();
    System.out.println(" "+Consulta1+(q2.next().get("X")));
```

The result:

```
_0
```

and I try this too.

```
for (Map soln : new Query("loco(X,Y)")) {
        System.out.println(soln.get("X"));
        }
```

The result:

```
_2
```

and this...

```
Query q2= new Query("loco(X,Y)");
    q2.open();
    System.out.println(q2.next().get("X"));
```

The result:

```
_0
```

I try with "q2.nextSolution()" and "q2.nextElement()" but the results were always the same "_N" where N is any number "0,1,2,3,4" and i don't know why.

Comment: maybe you forget to consult your .pl ?

Comment: OK nevermind bro i found the solution with getSubstWithNameVars();